# React onWheel/onScroll Functions best practice?

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, vertical-scrolling

So I have a complex animation I want to do on wheel with React. Essentially, when the user scrolls out initially, the page zooms out first to reveal me editing the page on a monitor. Then once it's reached its full width, It lets the user scroll down again. When you scroll back up it zooms back in. So all that is fine so far I've done everything I mentioned with one catch:

When you try to zoom out initially, let's say you don't move your mouse at all while scrolling, and that your scrolling is quick enough that you don't stop scrolling for very long to reposition your finger on the scroll wheel. For whatever reason it just sits in place and doesn't scroll until you move your mouse or wait a tenth of a second or longer.

So currently I accomplish all this by using a combination of onScroll and onWheel. I use onScroll to see if we're back at the top of the page so it knows whether to run the scroll in and scroll out animation or scroll normally. If it's at the top of the page and zoomed in still, the overflow is hidden, otherwise it's overflow: scroll-y.

Here's my code:

```js
  const [scrolledOut, setScrolledOut] = React.useState(false)
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = React.useState(0)
  const [scale, setScale] = React.useState(1)

  const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();

  function checkLocking(n) {
    if(n < 0.36 || scrollTop > 0) {
      setScrolledOut(true)
    } else {
      setScrolledOut(false)
    }
  }

  const handleWheel = (e) => {
    if(width <= 991) {
      return null
    }
    let scrollAmount = e.deltaY
    if(scrollAmount > 0 && scale > 0.35 && !(scrollTop > 0)) {
      const newScale = parseFloat(scale) - 0.05
      setScale(parseFloat(newScale).toFixed(2))
      checkLocking(newScale)

      return null
    } else if(scrollAmount < 0 && scale < 1 && !(scrollTop > 0)) {
      const newScale = parseFloat(scale) + 0.05
      setScale(parseFloat(newScale).toFixed(2))
      checkLocking(newScale)

      return null
    }

    return null
  }

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    let element = e.target;
    setScrollTop(element.scrollTop)
  }
```

This will lock or unlock this element with a ternary operator:

```html
<div className="App" onScroll={(e) => handleScroll(e)} onWheel={(e) => handleWheel(e)} className={scrolledOut ? "App unlocked" : "App locked" } data-theme="dark">
```

There's also some buttons that auto zoom out then scroll but that's not relevant. So my question really amounts to am I doing this right? COuld I be doing this better? If I'm doing it right how do I fix my scroll issue?

Comment: Your app's performance will suffer if you useState to handle scrolling, in these scenarios i think you'd better useRef or throttle it using the requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @KadirDamene This is a helpful suggestion. Could you give me an example with my code of how you'd go about this?